Возможен ли диалог, включённый в повествование?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли оформлена данная часть предложения, и если нет, то как исправить? Текст такой:
Нет, думает мужчина, нужно срочно что-то менять. Но что именно? Какие действия можно предпринять в подобной его ситуации? Он и так прилагает огромные усилия, чтобы начальство хотя бы заметило его, его труды. Но все старания как будто бессмысленны, и он снова не может заниматься тем, чем всегда мечтал.
Первое предложение в данном отрывке является мыслями персонажа, которые обычно выносятся в отдельный абзац и заключаются в кавычки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть варианты правильного оформления?

Я бы написала так:
Нет, думает мужчина, нужно срочно что-то менять.
Но что именно? Какие действия можно предпринять в подобной его ситуации? Он и так прилагает огромные усилия, чтобы начальство хотя бы заметило его, его труды. Но все старания как будто бессмысленны, и он снова не может заниматься тем, чем всегда мечтал.
Пояснение
Это несобственно-прямая речь – часть текста, передающая слова, мысли, чувства персонажа. НПР оформлена особым образом:  она совмещает свойства прямой и косвенной (авторской) речи.
Здесь плавный переход от авторской речи к НПР, нет кавычек, но текст нужно интересно оформить по абзацам. Примеры можно посмотреть в книге Акунина, начиная со слов (и дальше):
 И там, в подворотне, Ластик вдруг увидел силуэт, 
 показавшийся ему очень знакомым. Какой-то мальчик стоял 
 там, в густой тени, и, прислонившись к стене, смотрел в эту 
 сторону.
 Так ведь это я, это мое отражение, понял вдруг Ластик. Вон 
 и куртка красного цвета!
 Но какое в подворотне может быть отражение? Там ни зеркала, 
 ни витрины, ничего.

О несобственно-прямой речи
Несобственно-прямая речь (НПР) – это часть текста, передающая слова, мысли, чувства персонажа, которая оформлена особым образом. НПР совмещает свойства прямой и косвенной (авторской) речи.
Этот прием часто используется в художественной литературе и публицистике, когда автору нужно показать своего героя как бы изнутри, дать читателю услышать его внутренний голос. Приём несобственно-прямой речи впервые использовал в русской литературе А. С. Пушкин, после чего он получил развитие в художественной литературе.
Пример   из  романа  Ф. Достоевского: Но вот его комната. Ничего и никого, никто не заглядывал. Даже Настасья не притрагивалась. Но, Господи! Как мог он оставить давеча все эти вещи в этой дыре? Он бросился в угол, запустил руку под обои и стал вытаскивать вещи и нагружать ими карманы.
Сущность НПР заключается в том, что в ней почти полностью сохраняются лексические и синтаксические особенности чужого высказывания, манера речи говорящего лица, эмоциональная окраска, характерная для прямой речи. Но все местоимения и формы лица глагола представлены с позиции автора.
Наиболее характерный тип НПР — форма вопросительных и восклицательных предложений, выделяющихся в эмоциональном и интонационном отношении на фоне авторского повествования.
